# GPUImage framework always crashes on release iOS app

Tags: ios, swift, crash, gpuimage

In my iOS project I use Brad Larson's GPUImage.
All works fine when I install my app using Xcode, but when I install the app via TestFlight the app crashes every time I go to the viewcontroller that uses GPUImage framework.

I tried different solution but nothing:

- [Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10300800/ios-app-with-static-lib-always-crashes-on-launch-of-ad-hoc-archive-build-cant-r/10302012#10302012)
- [Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11102290/crash-while-integrating-brad-larsons-gpuimage)

This is my crash log, please help me:

```
Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x000000011b0b0000
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000001, 0x000000011b0b0000
VM Region Info: 0x11b0b0000 is not in any region.  Bytes after previous region: 1  Bytes before following region: 1412317184
      REGION TYPE                 START - END      [ VSIZE] PRT/MAX SHRMOD  REGION DETAIL
      MALLOC_LARGE             11afa8000-11b0b0000 [ 1056K] rw-/rwx SM=PRV  
--->  GAP OF 0x542e4000 BYTES
      Stack Guard              16f394000-16f398000 [   16K] ---/rwx SM=NUL  
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Termination Reason: SIGNAL 11 Segmentation fault: 11
Terminating Process: exc handler [18891]

Triggered by Thread:  6




Thread 6 name:   Dispatch queue: com.sunsetlakesoftware.GPUImage.processingQueue
    Thread 6 Crashed:
    0   AGXMetalG14                            0x1f32140e8 0x1f2d43000 + 5050600
    1   AGXMetalG14                            0x1f3126ec0 0x1f2d43000 + 4079296
    2   AGXMetalG14                            0x1f3126ec0 0x1f2d43000 + 4079296
    3   AGXMetalG14                            0x1f3126e48 0x1f2d43000 + 4079176
    4   AppleMetalGLRenderer                   0x1f1f58184 invocation function for block in GLDContextRec::modifyTexSubImage(GLDTextureRec*, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, void const*, int, GLDBufferRec*, unsigned int) + 112
    5   AppleMetalGLRenderer                   0x1f1f57c54 gldModifyTexSubImage + 1916
    6   GLEngine                               0x1beabb52c glTexImage2D_Exec + 1992
    7   OpenGLES                               0x1beb7bd68 glTexImage2D + 84
    8   GPUImage                               0x100de4978 closure #1 in PictureInput.init(image:smoothlyScaleOutput:orientation:) + 336
    9   GPUImage                               0x100e23844 specialized closure #1 in SerialDispatch.runOperationSynchronously(_:) + 212
    10  GPUImage                               0x100decf14 partial apply for thunk for @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20
    11  GPUImage                               0x100decd78 thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20
    12  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1802a3670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    13  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1802b28c4 _dispatch_lane_barrier_sync_invoke_and_complete + 56
    14  GPUImage                               0x100ded7d8 specialized SerialDispatch.runOperationSynchronously(_:) + 412
    15  GPUImage                               0x100de5348 specialized PictureInput.init(image:smoothlyScaleOutput:orientation:) + 1136
    16  GPUImage                               0x100de54ac specialized PictureInput.__allocating_init(imageName:smoothlyScaleOutput:orientation:) + 196
    17  GPUImage                               0x100de4770 PictureInput.__allocating_init(imageName:smoothlyScaleOutput:orientation:) + 24
    18  MyApp                                  0x1009c4cbc closure #1 in closure #2 in EditorViewController.metodoImpostaImgDaAsset() + 516
    19  MyApp                                  0x1009e0dcc thunk for @escaping @callee_guaranteed () -> () + 20
    20  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1802a3670 _dispatch_client_callout + 20
    21  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1802a6b44 _dispatch_continuation_pop + 504
    22  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1802b9c48 _dispatch_source_invoke + 1356
    23  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1802a6674 _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 500
    24  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1802b4de0 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 396
    25  libdispatch.dylib                      0x1802b5608 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 164
    26  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f19af0b8 _pthread_wqthread + 228
    27  libsystem_pthread.dylib                0x1f19aee94 start_wqthread + 8
```

Comment: May be bag in the GPUImage. Turn on sanitizers in the scheme diagnostics. If you will be able to reproduce crash with them then report this issue directly to GPUImage

Comment: @Cy-4AH Hi, thanks for the comment. I tried to turn on the sanitizers, but nothing. The crash is not reproduced with Xcode installation